# ZK - Dynamically load more results categorically

Tags: java, zk

I have a list of more than 5 users displayed in UI. I want to be able to dynamically load more users in a list, based on the category. If there are more than 5 users, then a label should be displayed, which when clicked, loads more users. Here is my UI code-

```
<vlayout id="vLyt" spacing="0px" style="background-color: #F6F6F6">
    <zk forEach="${categories}">
        <groupbox id="gbxCategory1" mold="3d" style="top:470px;">
            <caption label="${c:l('cpt')}" sclass="toggle_open">
                <div id="arrowUser" />
            </caption>
            <listbox id="lbxUser"></listbox>
            <div id="divNumOfUsers" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 4px; background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);">
                <label id="${c:l('labelMoreUsers')}" zclass="user_label_other" />
            </div>
        </groupbox>
    </zk>
</vlayout>
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to load the respective users in respective categories, because the list of users displayed in the UI is dynamic and hence, I won't be sure which category will be available to be displayed in the UI and which one won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create each Groupbox by Java upon categories, so that there is no problem to know mapping between users and categories.